# Why can't I disable iCloud keychain on my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, keychain

Running macOS 10.12.6. I'd like to keep this machine connected to iCloud calendars but prevent it from having a copy of my keychain.

[image]

Update: Someone suggested I go into iCloud > account details and turn off **allow approving with security code** but these are the only tabs that I see. Within the devices tab, I can only remove devices from my account. There is no other option.

[image]

Comment: Hm. Do you log in to your user account with your Apple ID? (Not entirely sure that would cause this--I don't use it myself--but it seems like it might.)

Comment: Nope local system account is not tied to iCloud in that way.

Comment: Go to Systempreferences -> iCloud -> Accountdetails. Deselect **Allow approving using security code**. Turn iCloud keychain off.

Comment: I don't see this option at all. I've updated the question to show what I do see when I open account details. Security tab only has a section that says TFA is on and an option to change my password.

Comment: I think Security Code was the old security method before iOS 11 and macOS High Sierra. Do you happen to have an iOS 11 device that updated security settings? I wonder if you need to update to High Sierra to get them on the same footing.

Comment: I'm not sure if my previous comment is right regarding this situation, but here's a link with some brief info on their new 2FA process: https://www.macworld.com/article/3225872/security/apples-two-step-authentication-goes-away-with-ios-11-and-macos-high-sierra.html

Comment: Yeah it does seem like the TFA features have changed with this new set of OS updates. I'm running iOS 11 on my phone but still running Sierra on my MacBooks. One of my MacBooks is corporate and the High Sierra upgrade is still gated behind infosec for now.

I read through that link @BrandonRader posted and but didn't see any mention of changes to keychain to would force it to be on.

Comment: Your Macbook is corporate? Is it possible that they are managing it with an MDM? It's possible they've locked that setting as well

Comment: It is managed but the policy is actually to _not_ use keychain because it's easy to accidentally tie it up with an iCloud account and end up storing your keychain in iCloud so I still think it's something to do with odd settings on my part

Comment: I wonder if they locked the setting but it was somehow enabled, so now it's locked as enabled?

Comment: Interesting but the plist settings files list things as enabled or disabled. I don’t think there is a setting to just lock a setting? Do you know where I should look for the plist behind the iCloud account settings?

Comment: Couple of questions: First: Do you have an Admin level account on your Mac? Second: If you go to the "Keychain Access" app does iCloud show up *and* is there anything listed there (make sure you are looking at the "All Items" category.

Comment: @sdmeyers yep i'm admin and there are indeed items in the iCloud keychain. i want to disable keychain on this work mac because i don't want it to have access to iCloud keychain items that i use on my personal devices.

Comment: This is a strange one. One more possibility, I can't see in the images above, but at the bottom of the preference window, is there a Locked lock? There is a setting to lock all preferences, so while it's not default for an admin, this preference could be locked which is why the check box is greyed out. Outside of that, you could create a new AppleID for this computer, then share the calendar with this new AppleID. That would accomplish your goal (though not actually solve the mystery).

Comment: Did you try logging out and back into iCloud? It's not bad, I would suggest that you accept "save" for everything when logging out and "merge" for everything when logging back in. Be sure you have a recent backup first, of course.

Comment: I'm having this problem on both macOS and iOS. Go to settings, icloud, uncheck "keychain". After a few seconds, it just re-checks itself. And all passwords remain on device. Did anyone ever solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think so. In my case, it might be due to a corporate policy that disables keychain but in a poorly executed way such that when I connect my mac to an apple id that already has keychain active, keychain is turned on but then the policy disables me from turning it off. 

Unless you are also using rooted corporate devices, it sounds like your symptoms are similar but root cause is probably different than mine.

Comment: I cannot replicate in 10.14.3. Is your account part of a family?

Comment: It is. I'm also the family admin.

Comment: Try applying the most recent software update first, could be due to security. If not, are there any permissions that have been altered? Are you able to log out and back in to prompt it to verify Keychain? Do you use Keychain to manage your passwords? Would resetting the Keychain lose any significant information? Open up the Keychain Access application on your computer to see if you get any errors as well, or needs you to verify anything.

Comment: Is there any other iDevice using the same apple id? If so, check whether iCloud Keychain is enabled in that.

Comment: I saw this site: https://www.saintlad.com/icloud-is-greyed-out-in-settings/. don't know it or tried these or how about Open Spotlight (Apple+Space) and type 'keychain access' and select the Keychain Access app. This app is used to store your usernames and passwords, and is also synchronised with your other macOS and iOS devices. ... Click Preferences from the Keychain Access menu and then click Reset My Default Keychain

Answer (score 1):

If Calendars is the only thing that this Mac needs from your AppleID, then one solution would be to give this Mac a separate AppleID, and share the Calendar.

Comment: counter question doesn't view like a constructive answer. Why not move that into the comments?

Comment: Changed from a question to a statement.